# SQL query comparing values from two columns, evaluating it and making the sum of evaluated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

There are four columns in the table:

```
COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT
```

I need to write a SQL query that will compare values in columns `PRICE_LEFT` and `PRICE_RIGHT`, and assign a value of one to column with greater value (otherwise assigns 0).

Next I need to make a sum of all ones and zeros corresponding to each value in columns `COL_LEFT` and `COL_RIGHT`.

So far I can only make the comparison but I don't know how to make sums out of all the values in both columns (`RESULT_LEFT`, `RESULT_RIGHT`) in `RESULT_TABLE`.

Here's what I got so far:

```
 WITH Tbl AS
 (
     SELECT
         a.*,
         CASE 
             WHEN PRICE_LEFT > PRICE_RIGHT 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS RESULT_LEFT,
         CASE 
             WHEN PRICE_RIGHT > PRICE_LEFT 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS RESULT_RIGHT
     FROM 
         SUMS_BY_VALUE a
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM Tbl
      ....
```

I am using SQL Server LocalDB database.

Here is the example of how it should work:

[image]

Here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE SUMS_BY_VALUE 
(
    COL_LEFT varchar(255),
    COL_RIGHT varchar(255),
    PRICE_LEFT int,
    PRICE_RIGHT int
);


INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'G', 22, 4);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('C', 'A', 15, 14);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'D', 5, 18);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('A', 'F', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('F', 'E', 4, 8);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('G', 'C', 16, 6);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('D', 'C', 22, 28);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('A', 'G', 14, 19);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('F', 'D', 3, 12);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'A', 11, 9);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('D', 'F', 8, 2);
INSERT INTO SUMS_BY_VALUE (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'F', 4, 1);
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
With CTE As
(
    Select COL_LEFT As Col, 
    Case When PRICE_LEFT> PRICE_RIGHT Then 1 Else 0 End as Result
    from SUMS_BY_VALUE
    Union ALL
    Select COL_RIGHT As Col,
    Case When PRICE_LEFT<PRICE_RIGHT Then 1 Else 0 End as Result
    from SUMS_BY_VALUE
)

Select Col,Sum(Result) As Tot From CTE
Group By Col
```

See a demo from [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0629bdd54b00fdca7176d4ab1fa009a).